# Compare two two dates in derived column of SSIS

Tags: ssis

How can i compare two two dates in derived column of SSIS.Please help me.I am very new to this.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add Derived Column Component into your data flow.
2. Configure your Derived Column Component

   1. In the first column, provide a useful name for your new column `DatesAreEqual`
   2. The next column remains blank
   3. The third column is where you provide your expression. Since "compare two dates" is rather vague, I'm assuming you want to see if they are equal. `[Col1] == [Col2]` would be the most simple version of a comparison. This assumes that the columns are never null and if they contain time components, you wish to compare those as well. Also note, that column names are case sensitive so `col1` is different from `Col1`
   4. Observe that the next column will be your data type and it is of DT_BOOL/Boolean

Comment: k...I am using DATEPART( "yy",GETDATE() ) to take only '13' from 2013.But it give '2013'.What i have to do to take alone '13'.I missed anything.

Comment: Why would you think using that formula would return `13`. The year is 2013. See [DatePart](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137586.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This expression worked for me in SSIS Derived column:

```
DateToCheck < (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2019-01-01" ? "Before 2019" : "After 2019"
```