# Is it possible to create input variable for Data Flow Task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

How to create input variable for Data Flow Task.And passing that variable from control flow to data flow in a package.

Comment: Yes; use a variable. What you describe is trivial, so can you expand the question and actually describe the problem and what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Variable. Unless you are using SSIS 2012, click on the background of the Control Flow. This ensures the focus is on the Package itself. *Then* create a variable. Otherwise, you will create the variable at the scope of *whatever* is currently selected.
2. In your Data Flow task, follow the same steps in your other question's answer by creating and configuring the Derived Column Component [Compare two two dates in derived column of SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524224/compare-two-two-dates-in-derived-column-of-ssis)

   1. Instead of using an Expression on columns, drag your Variable into the Expression box, so your expression would be `@[User::MyVariable]`